# How to make a loop with a Jquery subarray Json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have this array and I need to get the **public_id** and **format** values

```
{"resources":[{"public_id":"samples/3_zm3ex0","version":1643650862,"format":"jpg","width":4000,"height":3000,"type":"upload","created_at":"2022-01-31T17:41:02Z"},{"public_id":"mggvuz0xisg2nzkldbvx","version":1643520511,"format":"jpg","width":500,"height":549,"type":"upload","created_at":"2022-01-30T05:28:31Z"},{"public_id":"samples/cloudinary-group","version":1643517184,"format":"jpg","width":3000,"height":1526,"type":"upload","created_at":"2022-01-30T04:33:04Z"}],"updated_at":"2022-01-31T18:28:07Z"}
```

I try to do it like this but without success

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#fetch").click(function(event) {
                $.getJSON('https://res.cloudinary.com/dkx20emez/image/list/dom.json', function(emp) {
                    $('#display').html('<p> Name: ' + emp.resources.public_id + '</p>');
$('#display').html('<p> Name: ' + emp.resources.format + '</p>');
                   
                    
                   
                });
            });
        });
```

I appreciate your help

Comment: What are you trying to do? I can see your data has a list of objects. Do you want only the first values? What output are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **ressources** attributes is an array so you have  to loop each element in it. Your code should be like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fetch").click(function(event) {
        $.getJSON('https://res.cloudinary.com/dkx20emez/image/list/dom.json', function(emp) {
          //the attribute resource is an array so you have to loop each element in it
          emp.resources.forEach(function(element){   
            var publicid = element.public_id;
            var format = element.format;
            $('#display').append('<div><p> Name: ' + publicid + '</p><p> Name: ' + format + '</p></div>');
          });

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it works partially for me, but it only shows me the result of 1 subarray, any way to get all 3?

Comment: @MaríaperezKusky you can use the append function to add each element in the #display and each element is inside a div. I have updated the code. Can you check if it is working for you?

Comment: if it makes the bubble 3 times but it appears as "undefined"

Comment: I correct, if it worked for me, thank you very much